# How to run in a specific order many e2e files with Detox with Jest for a React Native app?

Tags: ios, react-native, testing, jestjs, detox

As stated I'm testing a React Native app with Detox (and Jest) and I'd like to have several e2e files with different purposes -e.g.: login, fill a form and so- and run them in a specific order (the log in e2e file should go first). Running them in random order wouldn't do the job.

The goal is to avoid having one huge file.

Note: I'm running the tests on iOS simulator.

Comment: Do you REALLY need to run in a specific order? The best practices for testing is to isolate both tests and test suites, making them independent of each other. It sounds like you're trying to do the opposite. Also, in that line of thought - you wouldn't be utilizing Detox' important ability to run tests in parallel (thus reducing total execution time significantly).

Comment: How do you run them in parallel simulators? I've read that it's faster for CI.

Comment: In a nutshell, With Detox over Jest, Detox utilizes Jest's inherent ability to do so. To activate that, use the `--workers N` arg: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DetoxCLI.md#test

Comment: Thank you @d4vidi! It was not working for me with some additional flags.

Comment: Oh, would love to get more info on that - perhaps you could try to get more details on the combo in question, and submit an issue? https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't, but keep reading.

Jest's conceptual model is that each test file is a unit and is totally isolated from the others. It makes things easier to reason about and it allows parallelisation. If your tests need to be run in a specific order then they are logically a single unit so need to be specified in a single *test file*.

However that doesn't preclude you from splitting your tests into several files. You can have one file which Jest recognises (e.g. `full-suite.e2e.js`) and have that file include several others (e.g. `login.js`, `forms.js`, etc.). That way Jest runs everything as one file, in your specified order, yet you can organise your individual tests in a way that makes logical sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone telling you can't do this for some reason, while it's a default in Jest is ridiculous.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const path = require("path");

const testFolder = "./e2e";

// Read and sort test files
const testFiles = fs
  .readdirSync(testFolder)
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js")) // Ensure only JavaScript files are considered
  .sort(); // Sorts files alphabetically, assuming they're prefixed as 01_, 02_, etc.

// Execute each test file sequentially
for (const file of testFiles) {
  console.log(`Running test file: ${file}`);
  const filePath = path.join(testFolder, file);
  try {
    execSync(`npx detox test ${filePath} --configuration ios.release`, { stdio: "inherit" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Test failed: ${file}`, error);
    break; // Stops running further tests if one fails
  }
}
```

have a node script.

Save this as `runInOrder.js` and use it like `node runInOrder` and it will run your tests by their NAME in order.